# Puzzle idea wanted: Locate a point from n/x known locations

Tags: puzzle

Am working on an open 2D world, random-generated game where the player will over time find certain, (apparently)randomly placed locations. The player is guided through other means to those locations to make them reasonably easy to find.
There is an arbitrary number of those locations and the player can view them on a 2D map.

Now for gameplay sake, I'd like that every further location they find, makes it more clear where a certain, special location is on the map (finding it could be the goal of the game for example).

When they have, for example 5 of them, it should be "relatively exact". I'm happy to provide the player some sort of geometric tools on the map etc. but the theme of the game is more or less realistic, so the map should not just magically show them the target locations directly triggered by finding the 5th location.
It should be a challenge...

All the locations including the goal one shall be predetermined when the game starts and it's unknown in what order the player will find them.

Does somebody happen to have an idea for such an approach?

My first idea was to use the centroid, aka gravity center of a polygon formed by the locations, but that can be somewhere entirely different when having 5 location compared to when having 8 locations. Thus since I don't know the order in which the player will find the locations, this does not work.

Am happy for any input :)

Comment: Could you provide a short sketch how you want to look it like on a map? Placing the points and the hidden last location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of potential approaches.

One is to place your secret location first, then draw a small number of (hidden) lines through it. Place your other locations along those lines. (They don't have to sit *exactly* on the line - clustering them *near* the line is enough) You could think of these as "[ley lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ley_line)" connecting important sites.

[image: Animated example of finding locations along lines]

With just a small number of locations found, it's hard to tell where the lines are, since *any* two points make a line. But as you fill in more and more, you can start to identify the pattern. Once you can spot two clear lines, head to the place where they meet to find the secret location.

---

Another method is to place some indicator feature at each of your locations that hints the *direction* to the secret location. Something like a standing stone facing a particular compass bearing. You can control the difficulty of the puzzle by varying how exactly you indicate the direction. In the example below, I snap the indicator to the closest cardinal/semi-cardinal direction, so you need more than just a few locations to triangulate the secret location's position.

[image: Animated example of finding locations with direction cues]

You could show these directional cues on the player's map as I've done here, or give them the tools to annotate the map with their directional discoveries once they notice/uncover this feature.

(Minor spoiler for The Witness follows)

> These obelisks in The Witness use this strategy. Each of the 8 faces of the obelisk lists the discoverable patterns that can be found somewhere in the 45-degree arc of the map in the direction it faces. This isn't a super precise guide, but enough of a clue to get the player looking in the right direction. In their case, the patterns are always close to the obelisk, so you could also consider using different cues for "this direction, nearby" versus "this direction, far"
>
>  [image: Witness Obelisk]

Comment: Those are some really cool concepts! Yes, either could work well. Thank you, this helped I think :)